# Why is my approximation of the Gamma function not exact?

Tags: math, applescript

So I'm setting out to recreating some math functions from the `math` library from python.

One of those functions is the `math.gamma`-function. Since I know my way around JavaScript I thought I might try to translate the [JavaScript implementation of the Lanczos approximation on Rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gamma_function#JavaScript) into Applescript code:

```applescript
on gamma(x)
    set p to {1.0, 676.520368121885, -1259.139216722403, 771.323428777653, -176.615029162141, 12.507343278687, -0.138571095266, 9.98436957801957E-6, 1.50563273514931E-7}
    set E to 2.718281828459045
    set g to 7
    if x < 0.5 then
        return pi / (sin(pi * x) * (gamma(1 - x)))
    end if
    set x to x - 1
    set a to item 1 of p
    set t to x + g + 0.5
    repeat with i from 2 to count of p
        set a to a + ((item i of p) / (x + i))
    end repeat
    return ((2 * pi) ^ 0.5) * (t ^ x + 0.5) * (E ^ -t) * a
end gamma
```

The required function for this to run is:

```applescript
on sin(x)
    return (do shell script "python3 -c 'import math; print(math.sin(" & x & "))'") as number
end sin
```

All the other functions of the Javascript implementation have been removed to not have too many required functions, but the inline operations I introduced produce the same result.

---

This Javascript-code works great when trying to run it in the browser-console, but my Applescript implementation doesn't produce answers anywhere near the actual result. Is it because...

- ...I implemented something wrong?
- ...Applescript doesn't have enough precision?
- ...something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two mistakes in your code:

First of all, the `i` in your repeat statement starts at 2 rather than 1, which is fine for `(item i of p)`, but it needs to be subtracted by 1 in the `(x + i)`.

Secondly, in the code `(t ^ x + 0.5)` in the return statement, the `t` and `x` are being calculated first since they are exponents and then added to `0.5`, but according to the JavaScript implementation the `x` and `0.5` need to be added together first instead.